# Remove <div> tag after form tag in user register form Drupal 7

Tags: theming

I have added this code to template.php

```
function mytheme_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  $hooks = array();
   // Make user-register.tpl.php available
  $hooks['user_register_form'] = array (
     'render element' => 'form',
     'path' => drupal_get_path('theme','mytheme'),
     'template' => 'user-register',
     'preprocess functions' => array('mytheme_preprocess_user_register_form'),
  );
  return $hooks;
}

function mytheme_preprocess_user_register_form(&$vars) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  array_shift($args);
  $form_state['build_info']['args'] = $args;
  $vars['form'] = drupal_build_form('user_register_form', $form_state['build_info']    ['args']);
}
```

also I have created user-register.tpl.php with this

```
<span>test</span>
```

but the result is

```
<form class="user-info-from-cookie" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/user/register" method="post" id="user-register-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div>
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

How I can remove the div tags between form and span.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `<div>` is actually there to ensure XHTML compliance so it shouldn't really be removed.

If that's not an issue for whatever reason, you need to override [`theme_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form/7), which is responsible for adding that `<div>`, and just remove it from the returned markup. The full code is quite short so I'll include it:

```
function MYTHEME_form($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if (isset($element['#action'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['action'] = drupal_strip_dangerous_protocols($element['#action']);
  }
  element_set_attributes($element, array('method', 'id'));
  if (empty($element['#attributes']['accept-charset'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['accept-charset'] = "UTF-8";
  }
  return '<form' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $element['#children'] . '</form>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems dangerous :) but it works perfectly!!!

Comment: Also, Firefox is showing a "&#65279" between form and span, do you know why? (this occurred before the reply also)

Comment: Hard to say, but I'd imagine it's related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)...